# Update table field Automatically

Tags: sql, ms-access, autocomplete, sql-update

I got dissappoined of lots of trying and seeking a solution through internet for this problem!
please help me out to solve it.

assume 3 simple Access Tables

1. - tblBox:

BoxID | BoxName|BoxColor|PlaceUsed

2. tblCustomer:

CustomerID | BoxID | CustomerName|CustomerCity

3. tblLocations

LocationID | CustomerID| BoxLocation

in this senario,Customers buy boxes and each customer could use their own box in a location (3rd table)
so each box can use in different locations by different Customers!

Nowwww

I want to update "automatically" the PlaceUsed Field of Box Table with the
"Last Location" in the tblLocation Field.
namely, regardless who is the customer, whenever a location has set in the field "BoxLocation" of tblLocations table for an owner who own a box, the 4th field of
the Box table get the value of that field (last location Used for that box)

how can I really do this?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a trigger for update ?

Comment: Because I am wondering of access  support triggers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Data Macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200).

However, if you use the Access UI, create a form and use the *BeforeUpdate* event.